# How to convert list of tuples as dictionary of lists with common item from tuple as key of dictionary?

Tags: python

Suppose i have list of lists

```py
list_l = [ ['txt1', 'val1'], ['txt2', 'val2'], ['txt1', 'val3'], ['txt1', 'val5'] ]
```

I want to transform this as dictionary below

```py
dict_result = {'txt1': ['val1', 'val3', 'val5'], 'txt2': ['val2']}
```

Also there are performance requirements as the original list is from **~800mb** of file contents.

Comment: 800 MB of data? You may want to start looking at appropriate packages and libraries. Think NumPy, Pandas and friends.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple for-loop :

```
dictionary = {}
for i in list_l:
    if i[0] not in dictionary:
        dictionary[i[0]] = []
        dictionary[i[0]].append(i[1])
    else:
        dictionary[i[0]].append(i[1])
```

But yeah, for a list of 800mb you should take a look to those libraries like @9769953 told you

Answer (score 0):

as @AxelRozental suggests but utilizing the dictionary pop feature:

```
dictionary = {}

for i in list:
    k = dictionary.pop(i[0], [])
    k.append(i[1])
    dictionary[i[0]] = k
```

Comment: `1[1]`  is typo. please correct (i[1])
unpacking can be more readable using `for k,v in couples`

Comment: thanks for catching the typo

Answer (score 0):

The [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) data structure is the simplest way.

You can do a single scan in the list and collect incrementally the second element

```
from collections import defaultdict
list_l = [ ['txt1', 'val1'], ['txt2', 'val2'], ['txt1', 'val3'], ['txt1', 'val5'] ]
out = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in list_l:
    out[k].append(v)

# defaultdict(list, {'txt1': ['val1', 'val3', 'val5'], 'txt2': ['val2']})
```

If the data amount could be critical consider to 'consume' the original list using pop function (as already told)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

```py
import pandas as pd
list_l = [['txt1', 'val1'], ['txt2', 'val2'], ['txt1', 'val3'], ['txt1', 'val5']]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_l, columns=('txt', 'val'),)
dict_result = (df.groupby('txt').agg(lambda x: list(x)).to_dict())['val']
```

---

**Details**

1. Create the *DataFrame*

```py
import pandas as pd
list_l = [['txt1', 'val1'], ['txt2', 'val2'], ['txt1', 'val3'], ['txt1', 'val5']]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_l, columns=('txt', 'val'),)
print(df)
```

gives

```py
    txt   val
0  txt1  val1
1  txt2  val2
2  txt1  val3
3  txt1  val5
```

2. Group the *DataFrame* by *txt* and [*agregate*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregations-with-user-defined-functions) the lists

```py
grouped = df.groupby('txt')
print(grouped.agg(lambda x: list(x)))
```

gives

```py
                     val
txt                     
txt1  [val1, val3, val5]
txt2              [val2]
```

3. [Convert the *DataFrame* to a dictionary](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict)

```py
dict_result = (grouped.agg(lambda x: list(x)).to_dict())['val']
print(dict_result)
```

gives the expected result

```py
{'txt1': ['val1', 'val3', 'val5'], 'txt2': ['val2']}
```